# asp.net deploy 3rd party dlls to bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, msbuild, bin

### BACKGROUND

I have created an ASP.NET webforms (4.6) website that has some 3rd party components in it. In order for this to work I have created a SharedResources folder that contains the DLLs needed. I've added a reference and those DLLs get copied to the BIN when publishing - GREAT. BUT there are some other DLLs needed that cannot be referenced as they are not valid assemblies or COM components.

### MY PROBLEM

How can I add to the build, dll's that are in a folder (SharedResources\3rdParty) so that when I click 'Publish' it dumps all those dll's into the bin folder of the website.

### WORKAROUND

(trying to avoid this)
I have set the dll Build action to "Content - always copy" and this gives me a folder of DLLs in  ~\SharedResources\3rdParty\ and then the application complains of missing dll's so I copy them to the bin manually - that can't be right!

Thanks

Comment: I might try this approach - any problems doing this 

>>>>


I don't know why I did not try this combination before, but including the bin folder and adding the dll files with "Build Action = Content" and "Copy to Output = Do Not Copy" did it! Thanks for leading me to this solution. Would it be right to mark your answer as correct or should I write a new one? – Alex AIT Sep 24 '12 at 12:21

Comment: try to publish with pre-compiled mode.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project go to properties and, in the build events tab paste this into your Pre-build event command line: copy $(ProjectDir)SharedResources\3rdParty*.dll $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work when you publish the website. You will have to create your own targets in the project file or a separate targets file and call as follows -

Add following -

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ThirdPartyDllDependencies Include="$(SolutionDir)..\..\Lib\ThirdPartyDll\*.dll" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PublishThirdPartyDllDependencies">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ThirdPartyDllDependencies)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ThirdPartyDllDependencies)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\" />    
</Target>


<!-- This target is responsible for adding the ThirdPartyDll and dependencies to the bin directory while Publishing the website. -->
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_CustomFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)..\..\Lib\ThirdPartyDll\ThirdPartyDll11\64Bit\*.dll" />
            <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
                <DestinationRelativePath>$(OutDir)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
        CustomCollectFiles;
        $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```